# Do I need a buck or a boost converter to charge a lithium battery with solar and wind energy?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, solar-energy, buck-boost, solar-charge-controller, simulink

I am doing a school project in Matlab Simulink to design a battery charger.

I need to use solar and wind energy to charge the batteries. Since both solar and wind are not always constant voltage and current, how can I correctly charge the battery?

In other words, how can I make sure that I always get the appropriate voltage to charge the battery even if both solar and wind produce high power at the same time or low power?

Comment: "Constant voltage" and "constant current" maybe do not mean what you think they mean. When we call a power supply "constant," we don't mean that the output can never change. What we mean is that the output will not change because of changing _load._ E.g., a typical bench power supply has knobs that adjust the voltage and/or current, but we still call it "constant" even though those parameters are adjustable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the DC DC converter needs to be able to draw the appropriate amount of current from the wind or solar load. Because of this a Max Peak Power Tracking algorithm must be used to find the optimal amount of power/current to draw from the load. You also need a charging circuit for the battery, the DC DC needs to know what voltage and current to run the battery at and when to shut off to protect the battery, a battery charge controller is usually used.

The MPPT algorithm can then output a signal, usually voltage (whatever the DC DC converter uses to limit the power (you can use voltage or current control)

I once built a peak power tracking algorithm in an FPGA, it would continuously monitor current and voltage, then multiply to find the power in the FPGA and then tell a DC DC converter through voltage how much power to draw.

Comment: You need a battery charger circuit designed for the lithium battery's rated voltage and current. Then you need a solar panel and a windmill and controllers for them to feed the battery charger.

Comment: MPPT is not a necessity. It's just a means to make sure that the solar panel harvests the most possible power from the available sunlight. A battery charger that provides appropriate current and voltage to charge the battery, on the other hand, _is_ a necessity if you don't want to damage the battery.

Comment: Yeah, you don't have to use MPPT,, but you will have power issues, won't be efficient and the power could drop out.

Answer (score 1):

The battery can be approximated as a constant-voltage source. By using it as a source you discharge it. By pushing current the "wrong way" through the source you charge it.

The battery doesn't care *how* you make the current go the wrong way.

Pay close attention to the datasheet, though, especially the maximum charging current and voltage. Lithium-ion batteries like to explode. The exact charging curve to use is out of scope here. The rest of the answer will assume you are taking care of this. Lead-acid batteries are much more tolerant.

The simple way is to just connect the solar panel, battery and a diode in series. The battery will charge when the solar panel voltage is above the battery voltage. When it's below, it won't. Solar panel voltage when charging is forced to be slightly above the battery voltage, so the panel can't operate at its maximum power point.

The more advanced way is to use (or create) a MPPT (maximum-power-point tracking) converter in between. This is a variation of buck/boost converter with different feedback. Instead of trying to keep the output voltage at a certain level, it tries to extract maximum power from the input. Solar panels produce the most power at a certain voltage and current, so the MPPT controller has to adjust one or the other to find the maximum power. This is then dumped into the output (connected to the battery) at whatever the output voltage happens to be.

Wind energy comes from a motor which produces AC, so you need something with an AC input. Although a fancy converter could draw sine wave current for low vibration and stuff, a plain old rectifier is probably good enough, followed by an MPPT designed for it.